# what does native language mean for a specific os?

Tags: java, android, operating-system, programming-languages, native

What does it mean that for example java (or kotlin) is the native language for android development?
What does native mean here?
Does this concept exist for other operating systems too? for example do we have a native language for windows and/or linux too?

EDIT:
I am not sure how much usual it is to use the phrase "native language".
The main thing I am looking for is what are the reasons that make a language more friendly and more frequently used for a special OS.

For example, is the api of an operating system more easy to call from one or a couple of specific languages? (if yes why?)
Is it the existence of compilers to compile to an intermediate set of instructions (like java byte codes) and to a set of instructions of several hardwares?

As another example we have some languages that compile to java byte codes, why are they not widely used for android development?

Comment: These are just language for development . And now `Kotlin` is the official Language for Android application development by Google.

Comment: Means from native langauge you can access or full control of os and hardware. So from java and kotlin you can do because android has a dex compiler and only native langauge run from the dex compiler.

Comment: A bit broad for SO, even if we only consider Android. For example: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-for-developing-apps-in-its-native-language-iOS-Android-etc-vs-a-cross-platform-build?share=1

Comment: @RishabhRawat, thanks for noting dex, I did not know anything about it and it made me to investigate about it

Answer (score 3):

> What does it mean that for example java (or kotlin) is the native language for android development?

From a technical perspective, it doesn't mean anything.

> What does native mean here?

It depends on what you mean by "here".  You claim that "native" is being used this way, but you don't offer any clear examples / references.

If we had some examples of what you were talking about, we could probably figure out what the author was trying to say.  But that doesn't *necessarily* make the author's use of the word "native" correct or widely accepted.

> Does this concept exist for other operating systems too?  For example do we have a native language for Windows and/or Linux too?

No.

And I'm not convinced it exists in Android either!  Certainly, I would not accept that it is normal usage to call either Java or Kotlin the "native language" for the Android platform.

---

Now there is an accepted use of the word "native" in Java for Android, Linux, Windows and other OS platforms.  A "native library" is a library (or dll) that is implemented in some (unspecified!) programming language and compiled to the hardware instruction set of the platform on which the JVM is running.   It consists of "native code" instructions ... not bytecodes.  The source language for a native library is *typically* C or C++, but it could in theory be any language that can be compiled to native code, and that offers a calling sequence that is compatible with (for example) JNI.  (Note that JNI stands for [Java **Native** Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) ...)

Comment: May be because of my Cordova background I have seen that phrase more, but it seems that its not Generally frequently used so I am going to write an edit note at the end of my question and I would be grateful if you express your idea about that too.

Answer (score 1):

### Low level programming

In contrast to Interpreted languages like PHP or Bytecode languages like Java and parts of c# a Low-Level-Programming means the compilation to very close programming for Processor-instructions like assembler and machine code.

### Native Android Apps

In contrast to Android-Apps a Native Android App contain code that is very close the device's hardware. Native Andoid Apps usually do not contain only Java bytecode. They use librarys or applications who are close to the Device's hardware.

There are two criterias for the decision if a Android App must be native:

1. A Hardware must be controlled directly
2. The performance of the Application is important (because direct controller instructions can be optimized and does not have the overhead of interpretation).

Answer (score 0):

**Long story short** for understanding the general consept -

Native means its a language for a specific platform.

That said, developing for android or for IOS (apple's OS) specifically each has their own native languages.(C is the native language for android [Kotlin is based on Java and Java is based on C] and Objective-C for IOS)

On the other hand, there are languages which are not native. For instance React native is developing for both the android and IOS platforms.
In these cases the views are not native elements but more web form elements (JS, CSS etc..).

Native languages will most of the time have better capabilities and performances.

Conclusions - Native means a language for a specific platform (the official platform language you could say).

Comment: ...`Java/kotlin for android...` How wrong is that! The native language for Android is **C/C++** (as for all UNIX platforms). In facts, the [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) (Native Development Kit) allows you to program in **C/C++**.

Comment: Tbh, your right java is native for kotlin while C is native for Android. I'll fix my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Never said it was.. but kotlin is based on java, hence java is native for kotlin

Comment: `... kotlin is based on java...` **correct**. `... hence java is native for kotlin ...` **opinionable**: Is it correct to assert that a language is "native" for another one? or is it more correct to say that a language is native for an OS?

Comment: @KlingKlang Sure than call it based on instead of native for.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the strictest sense, **native language** is just another term for **compiled language** i.e. languages which the product doesn't need to be interpretted at runtime. E.g. C, C++. I think the it's origin is closely related to the word **native code**.

Now coming into **Android**, it's top layer API is written in Java. As the language in which the OS components are written, Java is often called **native**.
 However, I wouldn't say it's a correct usage. Also, In Android, the toolset for development in Java is called "Software Development Kit" and the same for C/C++ development is called "Native Development Kit".

Answer (score 0):

The term "**native language**" for a **specific operating system (OS)** refers to the language in which the **OS was originally developed or designed to function**. In this context, "native" doesn't necessarily refer to the language spoken by the users of the OS, but rather the language in which the core components, system libraries, and user interface elements of the OS are initially developed.

- *Programming Language Native to an OS:* Languages closely associated
  with a specific OS, like Objective-C for macOS/iOS.
- *Native Code:* Low-level code specific to CPU/OS, often in Assembly.
- *System-Level Languages:* Like C/C++ for close OS interaction.
- *Preferred Dev Environment:* The language/tools commonly used for
  OS-specific development.

A native programming language for a specific OS is one that is closely tied to that OS and offers optimized performance and direct access to OS resources. While this can lead to high-performance applications on that OS, it may also limit the portability of the code to other operating systems. Developers often choose native languages based on their specific requirements and the target platform for their applications.